Trying to read/write /dev/mem on raspberry pi 4 without sudo
I am trying to read/write linux device /dev/mem using below code without using sudo on Rpi4 fedora IOT.
I am using BCM2835 driver ad dependency
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "bcm2835.h"
#include "bcm2835.c"



int main() {
  if (!bcm2835_init()) {
    printf("bcm2835_init failed. Try run with root privlages.\n");
  }

  if (!bcm2835_spi_begin()) // This condition is failing because bcm2835_spi0 == MAP_FAILED in bcm2835.c line 685
  {
    printf("bcm2835_spi_begin failed. Try run with root privlages.\n");
    return -1;
  }
}

User groups are
pi root wheel input tty adm mem kmem tape video ftp lock realtime cdrom dialout
ls -l /dev/mem is
crwxrwxrwx. 1 root kmem 1, 1 Oct 26  2023 /dev/mem

See also https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=22515

According to this blog post by the author of gpiozero you are using a technique that is out of date by two generations. You should be using [a library that talks to] the /dev/gpiochipX device instead, which can be given rights as a normal user.

I am writing a module for a software which is using /dev/mem to read write.

The correct solution "without sudo" is "don't use /dev/mem but specially created devices that do not give raw memory access"

You mean like gpiomem,  gpiochip0 and gpiochip1 ?

Those would be the "generation 2" and "generation 3" solutions mentioned in the blog post, yes.

/dev/men requires root -- period. You can use /dev/gpiomem for gpio access without root if you are a member of the gpio system group. Since both are deprecated (or at least strongly discouraged), why not use the current GPIO Character Device Userspace API?

Hi all I updated my code example can you please tell me what am I missing ?

Because BCM2835 driver is using /dev/mem that is the only reason I want access to /dev/mem without using root

One option (not recommended) would be to make your executable suid root (chown root a.out ; chmod +s a.out). That would remove the need for sudo but is also very bad practice and a huge security risk since your executable will be ran as root regardless of who starts it. But, it is an option.

I am not sure what is a.out ?

@9me "I am not sure what is a.out ?" - just the name of your executable. But seriously, don't go that route.

@JesperJuhl But then what option do I have to access /dev/mem ?
